# Set DatePicker to a date from the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I set the date for the datepicker in MVC 4? I can see the date come through, but am having trouble assigning it to the picker. Thanks.

```
<div class="form_item">
    @Html.RequiredLabelFor(model => model.Contract.StartDate)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contract.StartDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contract.StartDate)
</div>
```

Comment: trying using textboxfor instead of editor for

Comment: how would I display the date though?

Comment: if you set model.Contract.StartDate on the controller and pass it to the view it should be put in that field correctly.  Is it not displaying there at all?

Comment: Actually that works, but now it is in a textbox and not the date picker

Comment: I don't see a date picker being called in your code.  In ours we define the field and then in the script have $('field').datepicker() to initialize it

Comment: That makes sense, I will hunt down the script that should initialize it. Thanks!!!